# How to get access token for searching venues in foursquare

Tags: api, foursquare, access-token

How can i get access token for searching venues in foursquare.

From [this](https://github.com/ronaldwan/foursquare-api) gem, to fetch venues.

```
 venue = Foursquare::Venue.new(access_token) 
 venue.search({:ll => "37.792694,-122.409325"})
```

and from foursquare API.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/oauth.html

**Obtain an access token**

There are three general ways to use the new API.

Web server application

```
 (PHP, Perl, Ruby, Python, Java, Scala, etc.)
 Redirect users who wish to authenticate to
 https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate
   ?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
   &response_type=code
   &redirect_uri=YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI
```

etc etc.. other 3 methods of getting token.

But why i need token for searching venues. I just want to search venues.

PS: Basically I am developing a application and for that I need venues and Thats y i need foursquare api. ALL I want is venues and its tips, tags etc, nothing related to User's data on foursquare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a look on

[foursquare Venues Project (beta)](https://developer.foursquare.com/venues/)